How does life on this planet get enough iridium?
I am currently building a planet that weighs about 4 earth masses and it's radius is 2.3 times larger than that of earth's. It is an ammonia planet (as the title suggests), and has ammonia oceans with some dissolved water ice, methanol, hydrazine, chlorethane, and salts (sodium, chlorides, sulfates, potassium etc.). The average temperature is about 225ºK on the planet and the avg pressure at sea level is about 4 atm.
My plants use Chloro-carbonyl-bis(triphenylphosphine)-iridium (see this question's most popular answer for more info). It can carry both hydrogen and oxygen, which is useful for my life which need can use this blood to transport $H$, $CH_2$, and $NH$ radicals which are decomposed from ammonia, ethylene, and methane.
However, iridium is one of the rarest metals both in space and on earth, with a concentration of about 1 ppb on earth. That means my animals and plants with blood would die because of iridium deficiency. Even worse, iridium is a siderophile element so most of it will sink to the core even if it present in significant amounts.
So, how could iridium become concentrated enough on my planet for life to not die because they don't have it?

What PPB do you need?

@JBH Maybe something like 0.1 to 1 ppm (or 100 to 1000 ppb) which should be enough to extract like how life uses selenium on earth.

Your planet has enough sulfur
As Wiki states, iridium reacts directly with sulfur, producing iridium disulfide, which is a lot less dense than iridium (although a bit more dense than iron). In case your planet would get enough sulfur on top of whatever else, much of the initial iridium would get bound, and not go too deep into the core to remain available to the surface via tectonic processes.
Your planet has high volcanism
Perhaps it's not exactly a solitary planet, but a planetoid moon in orbit of a gas giant, that is also not (yet?) tidally locked to it, that causes enough disturbance to its crust to cause excess volcanic activity, which by some weird combination of magma, carries iridium disulfide into volcanic products. This gets dissolved into iridium salts and sulphur dioxide or similar compound (after all there's a FOOF out there somewhere, your chemistry could produce similar oxidants that would release iridium out of the less energetic form), and those salts could then accumulate or transition into other biology to not get submerged into magma.
